# YouTube api: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using YouTubeFragment in an Android app and getting following crash on Android 4+ devices.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.at.i(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.an.k(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.an.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.ao.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.q.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.at.g(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.ax.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.aw.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.a.av.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The fragment is being started like this:

```
 XYouTubeFragment yFragment = XYouTubeFragment.newInstance(ytVideoId);
 activity.commitFragment(yFragment);
```

and defined like this:

```
public class XYouTubeFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

    public static XYouTubeFragment newInstance(String url) {
        XYouTubeFragment youTubeFrag = new XYouTubeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", url);
        youTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        youTubeFrag.init();
        return youTubeFrag;
    }

    private void init() {

        initialize(Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) { }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    player.loadVideo(getArguments().getString("url"), 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        activity.findViewById(R.id.alert_list).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Comment: Same problem here, happens mainly with the Motorola XT1080 and Android 4.4.4.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you able to find the solution of this problem.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class YoutubeManager implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {


        String VideoTitle;
        String VideoIdLoaded;
        boolean videoTitleEnabled;
        boolean isPreLoaded;

        public void loadVideoWithId(String videoId) {

        }

    public static final String DEFAULT_API_KEY = "Your api key";
    String appKey;
    String searchKey;
    String videoId_local;
    String userId_local;
    boolean firstRun;
     Activity mActivity;
    YouTubePlayer mYoutubePlayer;
    private YouTubeFragment youTubePlayerFragment;
    private MyPlayerStateChangeListener myPlayerStateChangeListener;
    private MyPlaybackEventListener myPlaybackEventListener;

    public YoutubeManager(Activity activity, String key, int containerId, int windowWidth, int windowHeight) {
        mActivity = activity;
        appKey = key;
        searchKey = null;
        videoId_local = null;
        userId_local = null;
        firstRun = true;
        offsetTime = 0D;
        myPlayerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
        myPlaybackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        YouTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubeFragment();
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
                new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(windowWidth / 2,
                        windowHeight / 2);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        youTubePlayerFragment.setLayoutParams(params);
        fragmentTransaction.add(containerId, youTubePlayerFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(key, this);
    }

    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        mYoutubePlayer = player;
        mYoutubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(myPlayerStateChangeListener);
        mYoutubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(myPlaybackEventListener);
        if (!wasRestored) {
            mYoutubePlayer.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
        } else {
            //TEST of video playback
            mYoutubePlayer.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
            play(null);
        }
    }

    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            //errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            //String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void loadVideoWithId(String videoToLoad) {
        videoId_local = videoToLoad;
        mYoutubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId_local);
    }

    //Users
    public String getLocalUserID() {
        return videoId_local;
    }

    ;

    public void addUser(String userId) {

    }

    ;

    public void removeUser(String userId) {

    }

    public void removeAllUsers() {

    }

    //External Playback
    public void play(String userId) {
        mYoutubePlayer.play();
    }

    public void pause(String userId) {
        mYoutubePlayer.pause();
    }

    public void stop(String userId) {

    }

    public void close(String userId) {

    }

    private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements PlayerStateChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
            Log.INFO("YOUTUBE", "onAdStarted()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(
                com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
            Log.INFO("YOUTUBE", "onError(): " + arg0.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
            Log.INFO("YOUTUBE", "onLoaded(): " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            Log.INFO("YOUTUBE", "onLoading()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            Log.INFO("YOUTUBE", "onVideoEnded()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            Log.INFO("YOUTUBE", "onVideoStarted()");
        }

    }

    private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements PlaybackEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
            Log.INFO("YOUTUBE", "onBuffering(): " + String.valueOf(arg0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please explain (in short) what you did there, otherwise ppl won't find it much useful. Thank You!

Comment: Please give explanation what you did in this solution to overcome this problem. Your answer is not useful.

Comment: Above is whole class if only youtube fragment you need then use this snippet-   youTubePlayerFragment.setLayoutParams(params);
        fragmentTransaction.add(containerId, youTubePlayerFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(key, this);